# Why can't I ssh-copy-id to an EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a ubuntu Natty instance on EC2, and I can SSH into it by

```
ssh -v -i ec2-keypair ubuntu@ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But I'd like to set up password less sshing.  So I tried these options and nothing is working:

```
 $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).

 $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/ec2-keypair ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found

 $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I needed to run

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/ec2-keypair
```

Comment: I have done this for both postgres and my admin normal user still when I run `ssh-copy-id -f -i /var/lib/postgres/.pubfilename ubuntu@ec2-domain` still getting permission denied error.

Comment: Note in some environments, you'll need to run `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` if you see `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
scp -i ec2-keypair ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/
```

Then

```
ssh -i ec2-keypair ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And when you logged in:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
rm id_rsa.pub
exit
```

Now you can log with

```
ssh ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: `ssh-copy-id` gives the error `Permission denied (publickey)` on an AWS EC2 instance. I was sure that I set all the permissions correctly using `chmod`.

In addition, I needed to change this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I guess that's because `ssh-copy-id` asks for your password.

Then the error disappeared.

Comment: Beware though that changing the PasswordAuthentication from 'no' to 'yes' can lock you out of your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ssh-copy-id is confused about connecting with a key in order to copy another key.

My solution:

```
ssh-copy-id -f "-o IdentityFile ec2-keypair.pem" ubuntu@XXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Breakdown:

- `-o IdentityFile ec2-keypair.pem`: I'm using a "raw" ssh option to connect using the AWS-generated key.
- `-f`: ssh-copy-id tries to copy the AWS-generated key again, so force mode is necessary to copy the *other* key.